# How to achieve a clickable icon using an OnClick event in React that holds a setTimeout but also a clearTimeout?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

THE PHOTO BELOW SHOWS WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE. Basically I have a component where when I hover some arrows (up and down) appears but when the user click those arrows the background color changes, but just on the click itself. and the background color does not remain clicked. I tried to achieve that with a setTimeout on the click event. I can let the timer work on the click but the clearTimeout is not working. Any clues? the code is also below (after the photo).

[image]

THIS IS MY CODE:

```
//rafce
import React, { useState } from 'react';
// styled components
import styled from 'styled-components';
// icons
import { IoIosArrowUp, IoIosArrowDown } from 'react-icons/io';

const DurationIntervalComponent = () => {
  const [hours, setHours] = useState('0');
  const [showHoursArrows, setShowHourArrows] = useState(false);
  const [arrowActiveUp, setArrowActiveUp] = useState(false);
  const [arrowActiveDown, setArrowActiveDown] = useState(false);

  const incrementHours = (value) => {
    let timer = setTimeout(() => setArrowActiveUp(true), 500);
    clearTimeout(timer, 1000)
    setHours((prevHours) => {
      // if there is nothing
      if (!prevHours) {
        return '0';
      } else if (+prevHours >= 24) {
        return '0';
      } else {
        return String(+prevHours + 1);
      }
    });
  };

  const decrementHours = (value) => {
    setArrowActiveDown(true);
    setHours((prevHours) => {
      // if there is nothing
      if (!prevHours) {
        return '0';
      } else if (+prevHours <= 0) {
        return '24';
      } else {
        return String(+prevHours - 1);
      }
    });
  };

  return (
    <Container>
      <Row>
        <p> Interval* </p>
        <Inputs>
          <Selection
            onMouseEnter={() => setShowHourArrows(true)}
            onMouseLeave={() => setShowHourArrows(false)}
          >
            {showHoursArrows && (
              <p
                className="icon"
                onClick={incrementHours}
                style={
                  arrowActiveUp
                    ? { backgroundColor: 'red' }
                    : { backgroundColor: 'none' }
                }
              >
                <IoIosArrowUp />
              </p>
            )}
            <SquareInput value={hours} />
            <p>hours</p>
            {showHoursArrows && (
              <p className="icon" onClick={decrementHours}>
                <IoIosArrowDown />
              </p>
            )}
          </Selection>

          <div>
            <SquareInput />
            <p>minutes</p>
          </div>
        </Inputs>
      </Row>
      <hr />
      <Row>
        <p> Duration* </p>
        <Inputs>
          <SquareInput />
          <p>:</p>
          <SquareInput />
          <p>to</p>
          <SquareInput />
          <p>:</p>
          <SquareInput />
        </Inputs>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
};

const Container = styled.div`
  border: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
  border-radius: 15px;
`;
const Row = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 150px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 20px;
`;

const Inputs = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  p {
    margin-right: 5px;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    text-align: center;
  }
`;

const Selection = styled.div`
  .icon {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding: 0;
  }
`;

const SquareInput = styled.input`
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
  border-radius: 10px;
  outline: none;
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
`;

export default DurationIntervalComponent;
```

Comment: https://www.golangprograms.com/onmousedown-and-onmouseup-event-handling-in-reactjs.html You could just change it to the desire colour onMouseDown and then change it back to the original onMouseUp. It would actually integrate very easily as they are different than the click event.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I have already two different onClick events that moves the number in the input box up and down, according to the arrows up and down. How do I integrate the onMouseDown/onMouseUp just for the background color of those arrows?

I mean when the user click the numbers are going up, then would be mouseDown, in the mouseUp I should not put nothing in terms of moving the inputs?

Comment: You could still have it change on click but just edit the background colour on mouse down, so handle them as different events rather than as one